# is this need to add jars files to glassfish, or need other solution

Tags: java, compilation, glassfish

In my final project, i build tool testing to test JPA entity,this project based on web using JSF and primefaces UI and my server glassfish server,my tool test crud(create, read using JPQL, update, delete), and iam try to complete tesing using compile string, but iam get error from line 2, if this error means need to jars libraries or need other solution ?

and my second question, is this better solution to test any entity/ies at this way ? pls support me and thanks.....
  this is class test Create (insert data) ...

```
public boolean ReturnCompleteCreateTesting(String FilePath) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("package Testing;\n");
    sb.append("import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory; \n");
    sb.append("import javax.persistence.EntityManager; \n");
    sb.append("import javax.persistence.Persistence; \n");
    sb.append("import Entities.Employ; \n");
    sb.append("public class TestCreation implements Testing.TestCreate.DoStuff {\n");
    sb.append("@Override \n");
    sb.append("public void doStuff() {\n");
    sb.append("EntityManagerFactory emfactory=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(\"JPATestingPU\");\n");
    sb.append("EntityManager emanager=emfactory.createEntityManager();\n");
    sb.append("long ids=3;");
    sb.append("emanager.getTransaction().begin();\n");
    sb.append("Employ emp = new Employ(); \n");
    sb.append("emp.setDegree(\"20\"); \n");
    sb.append("emp.setDepartment(\"Software Engineering\"); \n");
    sb.append("emp.setId(ids); \n");
    sb.append("System.out.print(\"Save Seccessfuly\"); \n");
    sb.append("emanager.persist(emp); \n");
    sb.append("emanager.getTransaction().commit(); \n");
    sb.append("emanager.close(); \n");
    sb.append("emfactory.close(); \n");
    sb.append(" \n");
    sb.append("    }\n");
    sb.append("}\n");

    File TestEntity = new File(FilePath);

    if (TestEntity.getParentFile()
            .exists() || TestEntity.getParentFile().mkdirs()) {

        try {
            Writer writer = null;
            try {
                writer = new FileWriter(TestEntity);
                writer.write(sb.toString());
                writer.flush();
            } finally {
                try {
                    writer.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }

            /**
             * Compilation Requirements
             * ********************************************************************************************
             */
            DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
            JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
            StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);

            // This sets up the class path that the compiler will use.
            // I've added the .jar file that contains the DoStuff interface within in it...
            List<String> optionList = new ArrayList<String>();
            optionList.add("-classpath");
            optionList.add(System.getProperty("java.class.path") + ";dist/TestCreate.jar");

            Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnit
                    = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(Arrays.asList(TestEntity));
            JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(
                    null,
                    fileManager,
                    diagnostics,
                    optionList,
                    null,
                    compilationUnit);

            if (task.call()) {

                System.out.println("Yipe");
                // Create a new custom class loader, pointing to the directory that contains the compiled
                // classes, this should point to the top of the package structure!
                URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new File("./").toURI().toURL()});
                // Load the class from the classloader by name....
                Class<?> loadedClass = classLoader.loadClass("Testing.TestCreation");
                // Create a new instance...
                Object obj = loadedClass.newInstance();
                // Santity check
                if (obj instanceof DoStuff) {
                    // Cast to the DoStuff interface
                    DoStuff stuffToDo = (DoStuff) obj;
                    // Run it baby
                    stuffToDo.doStuff();

                }

            } else {
                for (Diagnostic<? extends JavaFileObject> diagnostic : diagnostics.getDiagnostics()) {
                    System.out.format("Error on line %d in %s%n",
                            diagnostic.getLineNumber(),
                            diagnostic.getSource().toUri());
                }
            }
            fileManager.close();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static interface DoStuff {

    public void doStuff();
}
```

Comment: Please don't ask 2 questions at once. For your first question, you say  "iam get error from line 2" - what is that error? What is in the logs? Does the code have any relevance to that question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your base question about Glassfish, you need to do one of three things: Deploy needed jars withing your war file, put those jar files on the the classpath used by Glassfish, or put the jar files in the lib directory under your domain. Usually:

```
[Glassfish installation directory]\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib\appLib
```

Or alternatively you can put them here:

```
[Glassfish installation directory]\glassfish4\glassfish\lib
```

But the former is the most appropriate of the two.